# Poor precision when editing?

Tags: edit-mode

I have a recurring problem with Blender 2.64: I import a model, I start to edit it then suddenly the precision decreases drastically so that I can't move anything where I want to (there are huge gaps between available positions.)

[image]

I think it's due to IEEE-754 floating point representation but how can I fix it?

(I didn't scale my model.)

EDIT: I just realized that when I move an something, the edit bar indicates:

D: 0.0000 (0.0000) global

D: 1.0000 (1.0000) global (with the example above)

So the picker may switched to integer...

[image]

Comment: Is it just with armature, or with meshes too?

Comment: meshes too... (the bone was just an example.)

Comment: Can you post a shot of the meshes too? The bone issue could be caused by any number of things.

Comment: It sounds like you may have enabled *Snapping*. See [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2834/599).

Comment: It was that! Thank you and sorry for duplicating!