# Lost the Move Tool

Tags: 3d-view, transforms

So I lost my move tool. When I select anything, the standard little 3D move tool interface with all the arrows is no longer visible. I started to use 'G' to overcome that, but now that no longer works. I can move stuff around with G in the UV editor, but it is really rigid and snaps to a grid. I can't use G at all anymore to move things in 3D View though.

I don't know what I pressed, but I messed something up pretty good.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2834/599

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you hid the [*3D manipulator widget*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Manipulators). To toggle it on/off, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>. As Greg also points out below, you have snapping on as well, See [Cursor is set to move by increments. how to reset to normal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/cursor-is-set-to-move-by-increments-how-to-reset-to-normal).

Comment: Also sounds like you accidentally turned on snapping - toggle it with `Shift + Tab`