# viewport woes : cant hold drag anymore

Tags: 3d-view

I cannot use hold up-arrow and drag my model in viewport with mouse anymore.. guess i must have turned on (or off) some settings, but cannot figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: If the 'up/blue' arrow is not visible, you may have locked Z location. If so, have a look to the object's properties, in the 'transform locks' section.

Comment: can you tell me where i find this transform lock ? I have looked at Translate : Constrain axis .. and nothing were ticked there...

Comment: Have a look here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3k9r.gif. But not sure this is your problem as you provide few indications...

Comment: As a guess if you use Transform Manipulator - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49549/transformation-buttons-disappeared, also maybe http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16318/lost-the-move-tool

Comment: it was neither of the two suggestions, but i uninstalled Blender and installed it anew.. and that solved my problem.. i have no idea what the problem was, but i am gratefully for you two gentlemens time and suggestions :-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Properties window > View > Uncheck "Lock to Cursor", it locates above "Lock Camera View". I just faced this problem LOL.