# blender only scales 1 block

Tags: modeling

well when I want to scale my object properly it will just always increase by 1 standard so when I need to scale something by like 0.873 I'm not able to do that also I can only rotate like 45grades each time any knows how to fix this?

Comment: possibly related to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/cursor-is-set-to-move-by-increments-how-to-reset-to-normal and you can scale, move, rotate exactly in this way: after entering mode, eg scale, enter the amount,  so "0.873" to scale to. or rotate  and then "12.5" to rotate 12.5°

Comment: You probably enabled the 'snap during transform' option (clicked the 'magnet' icon at the bottom bar of the 3D window).