# When I try to extend a shape they jump way too far

Tags: modeling, extrude

Whenever I try to extend a shape it jumps way too far and I can't extend it to where I want it. This could be an easy fix, but please tell me how. When a shape extends, instead of slowly extending to different lengths, it jumps to a super long length and I can't move it anywhere in between, just longer jumps.

Comment: maybe related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/cursor-is-set-to-move-by-increments-how-to-reset-to-normal

Comment: Press Schift+Tab and try to extend again. I think that you just extend with Snap during transform https://i.imgur.com/snPh3an.png ( Little icon of red magnet)