# vertices jump about when dragging

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bmesh

I am retopologising a mesh using shrink wrap modifier, but some of the vertices jump about when being dragged for alignment:

For example if I press <kbd>G</kbd> and drag the vertex below to the right a bit it, it will jump to the right hand end of the mesh.

Any ideas what is going on here,

Regards

---

Thanks for your responses hawkenfox / cegaton,

I have looked further into your suggestions.
As requested more info in screen shot with 3DView status bar.
[image: As requested more info in screen shot with 3Dview status bar.]

Note: "Snap during transformation" NOT enabled.
"Type of element to snap to" is Increment, also tried "Face" as you suggested but no luck.

I am new to the shrinkwrap modifier and its settings. 
I'm not sure what or where "Snap onto Self" and
"Project Individual Elements on the surface of other objects" are.
Here are the Modifier settings:

[image]

I have used this method on another mesh without any problems and only certain vertices on this mesh seem to be a problem.

I hope this helps

Regards

---

Yes, the shrinkwrap tool is used with the "bsurface" and grease pencil tool to speed up the retopology process. ;o)

Comment: Please use the [edit] link and add more information to your question. There are a few possible causes: It is possible that you've enabled snapping (see this link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/cursor-is-set-to-move-by-increments-how-to-reset-to-normal) or maybe the settings for the shrinkwrap modifier are the cause. We cannot guess from the cropped image you posted. Please change the image on the question to one that shows the bottom of the window and the settings for the modifier.

Answer (score 2):

You must have set your "Type of element to snap" to vertex or segment and have your "Snap onto Self" turned on. Check that Type of element to snap to is set to face. You can leave "Snap onto Self" on and turn on "Project Individual Elements on the surface of other objects"

[image]

Comment: Added changes to my request above, also new to your site protocol, sorry!

Comment: Any reason you are using shrink wrap modifier to do retopo? Shrink wrap is mostly used for baking normals when setting up cages for myself. Retopology does not require any shrink wrap modifier in place. Usually snapping to surface would suffice?

Comment: Yes, shrink wrap is used to automatically align retopo. vertices with original mesh, and when using bsurface it speed thing up.