# I can't move anything

Tags: modeling

so I was happily working away, until translate stopped working.
when i press g to translate a verticie; it doesn't move, although it gives the impression that it is.

when i press 1 and go into reference mode: it works again, and side view with 3.
but in the normal camera perspective: nothing works.

please why please?
I am fairly new to blender, i tried looking up a solution myself, no success.

[image]

Comment: How does it work when in preset ortho views? Is vertex moved smooth or by steps? Maybe related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/cursor-is-set-to-move-by-increments-how-to-reset-to-normal. Also try disabling Mirror modifier and moving vertex after that.

Comment: thanks for your help, but it's fixed, i'm so stupid. the magnet icon was on; snap during transform... ahhh i'm kicking myself haha

Comment: Then it probably wasn't moving in perspective view due to too big increment steps relatively to the view; and zoom level while in the ortho views was big enough to transform freely.