# When I edit vertices they move in whole number rather than decimals

Tags: objects

When I try and move some vertices, scale, extrude, rotate, all those things, it automatically makes it a whole number rather than decimals.

Sorry this is so hard to explain. Say for example a point I want to move is at 0 on x. When I try and move this, x will change to 1 rather than say 0.1. Then it will change to 2. So basically the intervals in which I move and extrude objects is different now.

Once again I'm really sorry for my poor explanation. I'm looking around in differnet settings but I don't even really know what I'm looking for. I'll try and provide a video if you do not understand what I'm saying.

Thank you!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2834/cursor-is-set-to-move-by-increments-how-to-reset-to-normal

Comment: Yeah that solved it @cegaton. Thanks to both of you!